# How to add new attribute to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After getting all values from model, I want to add another custom attribute to the ActiveRecord class (this attribute is not a column in db) so that I could use it in view, but rails does not allow me to add one. What should I add in its model class?

```
@test.all

@test.each do |elm|
    elm[:newatt] = 'added string'
end
```

error:

```
can't write unknown attribute `newatt'
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Only a scope or do you want so save it to the database?

Comment: I do not want to save it to database. I'm doing some processing in that each (see updated code), and I want to add some extra info to each element. It will be used in the view only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding extra run-time attribs to an activerecord object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584592/adding-extra-run-time-attribs-to-an-activerecord-object)

Answer (score 16):

try this

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :newattr
end
```

you can access it like

```
@test = Test.new
@test.newattr = "value"
```

As you may notice this a property, not a hash. so it uses `.` syntax. however, if you need it to behave like an hash you can do this without defining a new attribute

```
@test.all
@test.each do |elm|
    new_elm = {}
    new_elm[:newatt] = 'added string'
end
```

Lastly, I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. if this doesn't make sense to you, kindly rephrase your question so we can understand the problem better.

Answer (score 5):

Define virtual attributes as instance variables:

```
attr_accessor :newattr
```

Comment: `elm.newatt = 'added string'`

Answer (score 5):

If you want this only for your views and do not have any other purpose then you need not to add attr_accessor

```
@test.all.select('tests.*, "added string" as newattr')
```

here you are adding newattr attribute for query output of ActiveRecord with a value 'added string'

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean to assign @test to the ActiveRecord query, correct? Try:

```
@test = MyARClass.select("*, NULL as newatt")
@test.each {|t| t[:newatt] = some_value}
```

Another related solution is to make it a singleton class method, though you'd have to jump though more hoops to make it writeable and I intuitively feel like this probably incurs more overhead

```
@test = MyARClass.all
@test.each do t
  def t.newatt
    some_value
  end
end
```

Using the second method, of course you'd access it via @test.first.newatt, rather than @test.first[:newatt]. You could try redefining t.[] and t.[]=, but this is starting to get really messy.

Answer (score 2):

If it's really just temporary it doesn't have to be in the object:

```
@test.all
@test_temp = []

@test.each do |elm|
    @test_temp << {:elm => elm, :newatt => 'added string'}
end
```

Otherwise, there are also [good answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986792/non-persistent-activerecord-model-attributes).

Answer (score 2):

If it temporary, you can try this:

`@test.all.map{ |t| t.attributes.merge({ newatt: "added string" }) }`

Answer (score 0):

```
@test.all

@test.each do |elm|
    write_attribute(:newatt, "added string")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. and successfully bypass using instance_eval

```
@test.all

@test.each do |elm|
  elm.instance_eval { @newatt = 'added string' }
end
```

normally it doesn't run into issue, when use attr_accessor.  it appears when other DSL override "newattr="  which cause the issue. In my case, it's money-rails "monetize :newatt"

Explicitly use write_attribute doesn't work as it is the reason to raise exception in rails 4.x

Comment: how do you access the attribute afterwards?