# Add attributes to RoR object dynamically with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I would like to dynamically add attributes to a Ruby on Rails object so I can access them with an Ajax call. I understand that I can send the info with another Ajax call, but I would much prefer to add the `:first_name` and `:avatar_url` attributes dynamically. Here is my code...

```
def get_info

    comments = []
    allTranslations.each do |trans|

        if trans.comments.exists?
            trans.comments.each do |transComment|

                user = ...
                    class << transComment
                        attr_accessor :first_name
                        attr_accessor :avatar_url
                    end
                transComment.first_name = user.first_name
                transComment.avatar_url = user.avatar.url

                comments.push(transComment)


                puts("trans user comments info")
                transComments.each do |x|

                    puts x['comment']
                    puts x['first_name']
                    puts x.first_name
                    puts x['avatar_url']

                end
            end 
        end
    end

    @ajaxInfo = {
        translationUsers: allTranslations,
        currentUserId: @current_user.id,
        transComments: transComments

    }

    render json: @ajaxInfo

end
```

Out of the 4 print statements, only `puts x.first_name` prints, and none of the attributes are added to the objects when I log the results on my console.

Here is the corresponding Javascript and Ajax:

```
 $('.my-translations').click(function(){
    $('#translation').empty();



    getTranslations(id).done(function(data){
        console.log(data)    
        var transUsers = []

        ...

  });
 });

function getTranslations(translationId)   {
    return $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: '/get_translations_users',
        data: {
            translationId: translationId
        },
        success: function(result)   {
            return result;
        },
        error: function(err)    {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};
```

Any tips or advice is appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Out of the 4 print statements, only puts x.first_name prints

This is because when you call x['comment'] etc you call the [] method on x object and I don't think that the object is an hash. when you call .first_name you use the new attr_accessor created dynamically; i think also . avatar_url should work.

Does it work if you do instead:

```
  @ajaxInfo = {
    translationUsers: allTranslations,
    currentUserId: @current_user.id,
    transComments: comments

}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help!!! I found a great explanation and fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429274/how-to-add-new-attribute-to-activerecord  ... As it turns out, `attr_accessor` creates properties, not hashes and therefore it uses the `.` syntax. I ended up using the solution by  Chris Kerlin.

Answer (score 0):

I found this awesome thread that answers my questions: [How to add new attribute to ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429274/how-to-add-new-attribute-to-activerecord)

As stated by @CuriousMind `attr_accessor` creates properties, not hashes.

I solved this issue by following the solution by @Chris Kerlin

Thanks!